# Do we need xml file for doing Spring configuration using Annotation?

Tags: spring, annotations

I was reading about the ways of doing Spring configuration and came to know that there are three ways of doing the same viz:

1) Plain XML based.
2) Using annotation based.
3) Java Based Configuration.

I am comfortable with approach #1 viz. pure XML based.

Now, I tried to use the approach #2 viz. `Using annotation based`.

For example:

```
@Component("circleID")
public class Circle {

    @Autowired
    private Point point;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circle [point=" + point + "]";
    }
}
```

I expected Using `Annotation` there won't be any need of any **xml file**, but we still to have XML file for the following.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.point , com.example.shapes" />
```

So isn't using annotations approach we are providing information in parts, some by XML and some by Annotations?

I am not clear on this, can anyone help me in getting this doubt cleared?

Comment: Short answer: No, you do not need an XML file, you can do everything using Java configuration (annotations) if you want. See Spring reference documentation: [Java-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java). Learn about the `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations.

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks for your reply, for this case #2, do we need XML? Can you please elaborate a bit more. I have seen lot of code which uses the approach #2 so bit confused as we are using Annotation as well as XML (although lesser code in XML).

Comment: No, you do not need any XML. You *can* have both XML and annotations at the same time, but the XML is not *required*. You can also  do it without any XML at all, only using annotations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go through the link that your provided and hopefully things more clear than currently. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XML is not *required* for Spring configuration. You can configure Spring with pure Java-based configuration (annotations).

For example, instead of using the XML you posted in your question you can create a class with `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.point", "com.example.shapes"})
public class MySpringConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Spring ApplicationContext from annotation config
        ApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MySpringConfig.class);

        // ...
    }
}
```

See [Java-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) in the Spring Framework reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!